# How to best handle "polymorphic" JSON response

Tags: apex, json

I'm working with a 3rd party REST API which has a number of data types (e.g., PlatformAccount, Subscription, etc.). that may be returned from various endpoints, but all responses are of the form:

```
{
    'code': 5000,
    'message': 'msg text',
    'data': ???
}
```

Where the `data` member could be a single record or a list of records or any of the API's data types.  For deserializing the responses, I could declare separate response types, e.g.:

```
public class PlatformAccountResponse {
    public Integer code {get; set;}
    public String message {get; set;}
    public PlatformAccount data {get; set;}
}

public class PlatformAccountsResponse {
    public Integer code {get; set;}
    public String message {get; set;}
    public List<PlatformAccount> data {get; set;}
}

public class SubscriptionResponse {
... etc
```

But that seems cumbersome, so I had thought to have a single apex type, and to cast as appropriate, for example:

```
public class PlatformResponse {
    public Integer code {get; set;}
    public String message {get; set;}
    public Object data {get; set;}
}

PlatformResponse resp = JSON.deserialize(httpResp.getBody(), PlatformResponse.class);
List<PlatformAccount> accounts = (List<PlatformAccount>)resp.data;
```

But that does not work, as you cannot deserialize JSON to `Object` (which makes sense I suppose).  So instead I tried bypassing `PlatformResponse` by using `deserializeUntyped`:

```
Map<String, Object> response = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(httpResp.getBody());
List<PlatformAccount> accounts = (List<PlatformAccount>)response.get('data');
```

While this will work for a non-list response, the above fails with `Invalid conversion from runtime type List<ANY> to List<PlatformAccount>`.  I then tried a pair of generic response types:

```
public class PlatformResponse {
    public Integer code {get; set;}
    public String message {get; set;}
    public Object data {get; set;}
}

public class PlatformListResponse {
    public Integer code {get; set;}
    public String message {get; set;}
    public List<Object> data {get; set;}
}
```

But of course, the `PlatormListResponse.data` element has the same problem as the prior attempt:  You cannot cast a `List<Object>` to a `List<Not-an-object>` (a restriction that has always irritated me).  Finally, I tried adding an empty interface, implementing it in all of my data classes, and using it in the two response classes, to try to avoid the casting issue:

```
interface PlatformObject {}

public class PlatformResponse {
    public Integer code {get; set;}
    public String message {get; set;}
    public PlatformObject data {get; set;}
}

public class PlatformListResponse {
    public Integer code {get; set;}
    public String message {get; set;}
    public List<PlatformObject> data {get; set;}
}

public class PlatformSubscription implements PlatformObject {
... etc.
```

Of course you cannot deserialize an Interface (`Cannot deserialize JSON as abstract type: PlatformObject`).  So I'm out of ideas.  Is there any way to avoid declaring separate `DatatypeResponse` and `DatatypeListResponse` types for each Datatype that may be returned by the api?  I am aware of `JSONParser` but I'm not looking to swap deserialization for parsing; I'll add all the various response types if there is no other option.

Comment: I think this is actually a good use case for a parser since you can put logic into the parser to have it treat the data differently. If you were to write constructors it should be doable to take `List<Object>` and convert to `List<Some_Object>` in your constructor.

Comment: I think I've tried to do stuff in the constructor of an object before and again got stuck - because the JSON parser doesn't invoke the constructor. That was a bummer.

Comment: Can't you use `instanceOf` on the Object to decide if it is a List<Object> ? and then further use instanceOf to decide between casting to list<specificobject> versus singleton <specificObject>?

Comment: @cropredy the issue is, I cannot cast List<Object> to any other list type.  My only option would be to iterate the List and cast each Object in turn, which seems excessive, and would require a separate cast loop per response type, since you cannot pass a Type as a param and use it to cast.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider this approach, where (assuming you have figured out the payload type), you turn the `data` back to JSON and then deserialize just that part:

```
List<PlatformAccount> accounts = (List<PlatformAccount>) JSON.deserialize(
    JSON.serialize(response.get('data')),
    List<PlatformAccount>.class
);
```

While it feels a bit crazy to go back to JSON and parse again, it does allow the parsing job to be broken down into pieces, and I have seen this approach used in production code.

Comment: I think I considered this briefly while brainstorming, and dismissed it as too... something?  But you are right, it does look clean; I may have to benchmark this a bit with real responses and see how it performs.

Comment: Yeah @JasonClark it is a pretty weird pattern.

Comment: So you'd deserialize untyped for the code, message and data... then serialize and deserialize into your desired class type for the payload? That'd work.

Comment: Yeah @CasparHarmer, poke around in the nested maps - at the root or further down if necessary - and once the type is identified, invoke the specific typed deserialize.

Comment: I actually started to write a parser for this answer...  but decided that just doing it your way while slightly non standard just used so much less code. I'm sure it's pretty performant as well.